# Turnstile vs Mutex

Tags: multithreading, concurrency, operating-system, synchronization, mutex

The question is related to a synchronisation mechanism called Turnstile. Examples of implementations and documentation can be found [here](http://sunsite.uakom.sk/sunworldonline/swol-08-1999/swol-08-insidesolaris.html), [here](https://github.com/NetBSD/src/blob/trunk/sys/kern/kern_turnstile.c) and [here](https://github.com/illumos/illumos-gate/blob/master/usr/src/uts/common/os/turnstile.c). After doing some research I still cannot find answers to the following questions.

- What problem does turnstile solve ?
- What advantage can turnstile offer as opposed to mutex ?
- What is the ownership relation between a thread and the turnstile ? (if any).
- If we reduce the complexity of those implementations, what is the bare bones minimal structure of a turnstile ?

Answer (score 0):

After reading the solaris docs more thoroughly, I was able to grasp the basic idea, so I will answer to my own question.

> What problem does turnstile solve ?
>   What advantage can turnstile offer as opposed to mutex ?
>   What is the ownership relation between a thread and the turnstile ? (if any).

Turnstile can help to reduce the amount of mutexes (or any other synchronization unit). When we want to guard an object with some lock using turnstiles, the lock becomes a lightweight object which delegates all operations to the turnstile. Each thread can be related to at most one turnstile. Hence #turnstiles ≤ #threads. This approach helps to reduce the number of inactive locks. However there is no some explicit ownership between threads and turnstiles AFAIK.

> If we reduce the complexity of those implementations, what is the bare
>   bones minimal structure of a turnstile ?

We can implement a naive turnstile in the following way.

Allocate a global pool of `Turnstiles` with operations `get` and `put` (obviously it has to be thread safe). Lockless stack can be a relatively easy and efficient implementation for the pool. `TurnstileLock` is the object which will replace our locks and mutexes and delegate the responsibility to `Turnstile`. `TurnstileLock` holds a nullable pointer to a `Turnstile`.

When some thread wants to enter the critical section guarded by the `TurnstileLock`, it checks if `TurnstileLock.currentTurnstile` is null (it has to be null by default).

- If it is null the thread takes a turnstile from the pool and assigns it to `TurnstileLock.currentTurnstile`, increments `TurnstileLock.currentTurnstile.waitingCount` and enters the critical section.
- Else the thread has to increment `TurnstileLock.currentTurnstile.waitingCount` and wait on some condition variable which has to be accessible via `currentTurnstile`

When some thread wants to leave the critical section (or free the lock), it has to  check if `TurnstileLock.currentTurnstile.waitingCount > 0` (after decrementing)

- If yes then it needs to notify the condition variable on which other threads are sleeping.
- Else put `TurnstileLock.currentTurnstile` back into the pool and set `TurnstileLock.currentTurnstile` to null

Comment: The [Little Book of Semaphores](https://greenteapress.com/wp/semaphores/) introduces the idea of a Turnstile while describing how to implement a Barrier mechanism (Section 3.6).Worth the read.